# Image in upgraded content databases is in picture library but appears as broken image

Tags: 2010, upgrade, image

This happens in at least one place in our farm, and until our QA co-ordinator points out other places I cant comment on if this is widespread or not.

On one page, there is an image that appears as a broken image, however going to the picture library shows that it is in fact present and the thumbnail is not broken.

Clicking on the image, goes to a display page with a broken image, however I can download it and it appears fine.

Renaming the image and re-uploading it produces the same thing, a broken image.

This is a 2007 to 2010 upgrade.

Anyone have anything like this occur?

Comment: Can you confirm the URL of the broken image is the correct?

Comment: Yes. The url of the image is correct.

Comment: Do you have the blob cache enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this issue very recently as I am performing a rather large upgrade.

I have looked into the Fiddler responses and they were not indicative so I downloaded the image and resaved it using Gimp (using all the default JPG settings).

after uploading this new image the issue is fixed.

I have successfully performed that remedy twice and I cannot explain why the same image works fine in my parallel SP2007 farm which I'm in the process of upgrading.

Are some JPGs not like others? Perhaps, however, I wish I could give you a more quantitative answer, try re-saving it in PS/Gimp/Paint and let me know if this fixes it.

Comment: Exactly. I had a similar issue before. Try saving it using Paint or something and try uploading it again. Its just the way you are saving that is causing the issue.

Comment: Since I dont have GIMP i just tried it in Paint and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps that resolved the issue for me:

1. Select a view with broken images in **Thumbnails** view mode
2. Choose **Site Actions** -> **Edit Page**
3. From the library Web Part's Edit drop-down, choose **Edit Web Part**, **Apply**, and **OK**
4. When you Exit Edit Mode, the Thumbnails appear correctly
5. Repeat for each view with broken Thumbnails

Comment: This is the fix for it, I was hoping someone might have come up with a script that could iteratate through the sites and perform this programatically..